# Let $( W_t )$ be the standard Brownian Motion then solve $\int_0^T (W_t)^5 dW_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am not sure whether I have solved it correctly. I need guidance. Thanks

To solve the stochastic integral

$$
\int_0^T (W_t)^5 dW_t,
$$

we use Itô's formula. Let $( F(W_t) = \frac{1}{6} (W_t)^6 ).$ Then, Itô's formula gives

$$
dF(W_t) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial F}{\partial W_t} dW_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial W_t^2} (dW_t)^2.
$$

Since $( F(W_t) = \frac{1}{6} (W_t)^6 )$, we have

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial W_t} = (W_t)^5, \quad \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial W_t^2} = 5(W_t)^4.
$$

Also, $( \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = 0 )$ because $( F )$ does not explicitly depend on $( t )$. Recall that $( (dW_t)^2 = dt )$. Thus,

$$
dF(W_t) = (W_t)^5 dW_t + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 5(W_t)^4 dt.
$$

Integrating both sides from 0 to ( T ),

$$
\int_0^T dF(W_t) = \int_0^T (W_t)^5 dW_t + \frac{5}{2} \int_0^T (W_t)^4 dt.
$$

The left-hand side becomes

$$
F(W_T) - F(W_0) = \frac{1}{6} (W_T)^6 - \frac{1}{6} (W_0)^6 = \frac{1}{6} (W_T)^6,
$$

since $( W_0 = 0 )$. Therefore,

$$
\int_0^T (W_t)^5 dW_t = \frac{1}{6} (W_T)^6 - \frac{5}{2} \int_0^T (W_t)^4 dt.
$$

Comment: Looks right. $\phantom{.}$